# In my program why does "if and else statement" runs into segmentation error?

Tags: c

//This code which has if and else statement runs into segmentation fault (core dump)

```
void print(struct node *tail)
{
    if (tail == NULL)
    {
        printf("No node in the list.");
    }
    else if (tail == tail->next) //If there is only one node.
    {
        printf("%d", tail->data);
    }
    struct node *temp = tail->next;
    do
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    } while (temp != tail->next);
    printf("\n");
}
```

The code below is corrected and runs fine.

What is wrong with the above code?

```
void print(struct node *tail)
{
    //If there is no node in the list.
    if (tail == NULL)
    {
        printf("No node in the list.");
    }
    else if (tail == tail->next) //If there is only one node.
    {
        printf("%d", tail->data);
    }
    else
    {
        struct node *temp = tail->next;
        do
        {
            printf("%d ", temp->data);
            temp = temp->next;
        } while (temp != tail->next);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You don't need the second `if`, as it is covered by the `while` lopp anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in the first code snippet is that when `tail` is NULL, you still try to dereference `tail` later on in the code:

```
if (tail == NULL)
{
    printf("No node in the list.");
}
[...]

struct node *temp = tail->next;   // Trying to access tail->next when tail is NULL!  Boom!
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. In the first code, the statement after if and else block will get execute irrespective of the tail is NULL or not. if that is the case then why it runs into segfault when tail is not NULL?

Comment: Perhaps temp gets set to null and then you try to dereference temp?  You can experiment and figure out the answers to that sort of question yourself, either by stepping through your program with a debugger or by adding temporary statements like printf(“temp=%p\n”, temp) at various locations and reading the program’s output to see what gets printed.

Comment: Thanks. I did exactly as you advised and the result is the second code. Though I managed to resolve the issue but failed to understand between my first code and second code. I want to know the logic so that it can help me in future. Thanks again for trying to help me.

Comment: The logic is, don't try to dereference NULL or invalid pointers :)